# What package am I missing if inline asm() is not supported?

Tags: gcc, libtool

I am trying to compile the PHP xhprof extension.  On one server, `make` is successful, on another one it fails with "inline asm() not supported". 
The relevant code is

```
asm volatile("rdtsc" : "=a" (__a), "=d" (__d));
```

Both servers run Debian with similar configuration.

**Question:** What package am I missing or which packages version should I compare between the servers to enable inline asm?

For reference the make output

```
/bin/sh /usr/local/src/xhprof/extension/libtool --mode=compile cc  -I. -I/usr/local/src/xhprof/extension -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/usr/local/src/xhprof/extension/include -I/usr/local/src/xhprof/extension/main -I/usr/local/src/xhprof/extension -I/usr/include/php5 -I/usr/include/php5/main -I/usr/include/php5/TSRM -I/usr/include/php5/Zend -I/usr/include/php5/ext -I/usr/include/php5/ext/date/lib  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g   -c /usr/local/src/xhprof/extension/xhprof.c -o xhprof.lo
libtool: compile:  cc -I. -I/usr/local/src/xhprof/extension -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/usr/local/src/xhprof/extension/include -I/usr/local/src/xhprof/extension/main -I/usr/local/src/xhprof/extension -I/usr/include/php5 -I/usr/include/php5/main -I/usr/include/php5/TSRM -I/usr/include/php5/Zend -I/usr/include/php5/ext -I/usr/include/php5/ext/date/lib -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -c /usr/local/src/xhprof/extension/xhprof.c  -DPIC -o .libs/xhprof.o
/usr/local/src/xhprof/extension/xhprof.c:1224: inline asm() not supported
/usr/local/src/xhprof/extension/libtool: line 1111: 23098 Segmentation fault      cc -I. -I/usr/local/src/xhprof/extension -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/usr/local/src/xhprof/extension/include -I/usr/local/src/xhprof/extension/main -I/usr/local/src/xhprof/extension -I/usr/include/php5 -I/usr/include/php5/main -I/usr/include/php5/TSRM -I/usr/include/php5/Zend -I/usr/include/php5/ext -I/usr/include/php5/ext/date/lib -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -c    /usr/local/src/xhprof/extension/xhprof.c -DPIC -o .libs/xhprof.o
make: *** [xhprof.lo] Error 1
```

Comment: Check what compiler you are using. `which cc`, `cc --version`, etc.

Comment: @MarcGlisse Thank you very much, you solved my problem.  The compiler used was tcc, on the working server gcc.  I did not notice this, because I saw that gcc-4.* was installed but the base package "gcc" was not.  If you could enter your comment as an answer, I could accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently `cc` on this machine is not a link to `gcc` but to some other compiler (`tcc`) which doesn't understand gcc's extended asm syntax.

Comment: I have the same problem as described above. Could you please explain for simple minded people as me, how to fix this? Thank you.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install build-essential` (or `gcc` or `g++`...)

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that the error message means "the assembly code itself is not supported", not that the `asm()` compiler feature isn't? In other words, you're building for some (semi-ancient) processor which doesn't have the `rdtsc` instruction?

The seg fault right after the error is kind of scary, though.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your answer.  The are different kernels on the servers and the linux image on the problematic server might be special.  I will try to change it to a more default kernel and try again.